# Outlook web add in addHandlerAsync error 5001 when registering functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, outlook-web-addins

I've been working with various different prototypes for a new Outlook Web Add-in and all of them have worked as intended/expected, today however my code for registering `Office.EventType.ItemChanged` has stopped working and I can't work out why.

Capturing the error returns a generic `OSF.DDA.Error "An internal error has occurred." code: 5001` as shown below:

```
error: OSF.DDA.Error {
    name: "Internal Error",
    message: "An internal error has occurred.",
    code: 5001 } status: "failed"
```

The way I am trying to set this up is below and is called from the constructor of the top level React component:

```
begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false
```

language: lang-js

```
Office.initialize = () => {    
    // Handle changing selected email - This is where the error generated
    Office.context.mailbox.addHandlerAsync(Office.EventType.ItemChanged, this.itemChanged, this.handleFailedChange);

    // Handle authentication - This is working perfectly
    Office.context.mailbox.getUserIdentityTokenAsync(this.callBack);

    this.setState({
        ...this.state,
        isOfficeInitialized: true,
    });
};
```

The error throws when the addHandlerAsync is called and clicking between emails then fails to trigger the event, the `getUserIdentityTokenAsync()` method is called and is working as the add-in is authenticating as expected so the error isn't preventing execution flow.

I tried moving the Office.initialize call out of the constructor but this failed to resolve the issue in addition to making it harder to track the isOfficeInitalized state that I rely on to ensure things are ready.

The code is ReactJS and using TypeScript to ensure coding. As mentioned above I have everything else working, which includes loading the selected mail item when the add-in is first opened - I fetch the subject, sender and Cc addresses out of it - so I know the Office.js file is working and running as intended.

Any help would be great, thanks in advance!

**EDIT - Solution:**

So after posting this and spending some more time trying to get this working, I checked the manifest.xml file... it turns out that the addHandlerAsync method is only available after API 1.5 and the minimal version in my file was 1.3, setting the DefaultMinVersion="1.5" has resolved this:

```
<VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_1">
      <Requirements>
        <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.5">
          <bt:Set Name="Mailbox" />
        </bt:Sets>
      </Requirements>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after posting this and spending some more time trying to get this working, I checked the manifest.xml file... it turns out that the addHandlerAsync method is only available after API 1.5 and the minimal version in my file was 1.3, setting the DefaultMinVersion="1.5" has resolved this:

```
<VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_1">
      <Requirements>
        <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.5">
          <bt:Set Name="Mailbox" />
        </bt:Sets>
      </Requirements>
```